# Create a new DataFrame based on conditions applied to another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-formatting

I have a DataFrame as follows:

```py
data = [[99330,12,122], [1123,1230,1287], [123,101,812739], [1143,12301230,252]] 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-04'], columns=['col_A', 'col_B', 'col_C']) 
df1 = df1/df1.shift(1)-1 
df1['mean'] = df1.mean(axis=1) 
df1['upper'] = df1['mean'] + df1.filter(regex='col').std(axis=1)
```

df1:

```
            col_A      col_B          col_C        mean         upper
2022-01-01  NaN        NaN            NaN          NaN          NaN
2022-01-02  -0.988694  101.500000     9.549180     36.686829    93.063438
2022-01-03  -0.890472  -0.917886      630.498834   209.563492   574.104192
2022-01-04  8.292683   121793.356436  -0.999690    40600.216476 110915.538448
```

I want to create a second DataFrame only with the values of `col_A, col_B, col_C` that are greater than `df['upper']` and fill all other values with `nan`.

So the DataFrame should look like this

df2:

```
            col_A      col_B          col_C        
2022-01-01  NaN        NaN            NaN          
2022-01-02  NaN        101.500000     NaN
2022-01-03  NaN        NaN            630.498834   
2022-01-04  NaN        121793.356436  NaN
```

Is there a way to do this Pythonically without having to go through many loops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter the "col" columns and make a vectorized greater-than comparison using `gt()` on axis and mask the unwanted values via `where()` method.

```py
# replace the values in "col" columns that are less than df1.upper
df2 = df1.filter(like='col').where(lambda x: x.ge(df1['upper'], axis=0))
df2
```

[image: res]

Answer (score 1):

Try this... not sure if this is the best way, as I did use one for loop...

```
import numpy as np 
data = [[99330,12,122], [1123,1230,1287], [123,101,812739], [1143,12301230,252]] 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-04'], columns=['col_A', 'col_B', 'col_C']) 
df1 = df1/df1.shift(1)-1 
df1['mean'] = df1.mean(axis=1) 
df1['upper'] = df1['mean'] + df1.filter(regex='col').std(axis=1)
df2 = df1.copy()
for col in cols:
    if "col" in col:
        df2[col] = df2.apply(lambda x: x[col] if x[col] > x["upper"] else np.nan,axis=1)
        
df2 = df2[[col for col in df1.columns if "col" in col]]

# Output...

            col_A          col_B       col_C
2022-01-01    NaN            NaN         NaN
2022-01-02    NaN     101.500000         NaN
2022-01-03    NaN            NaN  630.498834
2022-01-04    NaN  121793.356436         NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lambda` functions to achieve this

```
import numpy as np

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-04'], columns=['col_A', 'col_B', 'col_C']) 

df2['col_A'] = df1.apply(lambda x: x.col_A if x.col_A > x.upper else np.nan, axis=1)
df2['col_B'] = df1.apply(lambda x: x.col_B if x.col_B > x.upper else np.nan, axis=1)
df2['col_C'] = df1.apply(lambda x: x.col_C if x.col_C > x.upper else np.nan, axis=1)
```